# Is Contains Equivalent To Like In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, contains, sql-like

When I'm running this query:

```
Select * from Table1 Where Column1 Like 'aaa%' --3 Result
Select * from Table1 Where Column1 Like 'a%' --3 Result
Select * from Table1 Where Column1 Like 'A%' --3 Result
```

but when I'm running

```
Select * from Table1 Where Contains(Column1 ,'aaa') --3 Result
Select * from Table1 Where Contains(Column1 ,'a') --0 Result
Select * from Table1 Where Contains(Column1 ,'A') --0 Result
```

`CONTAINS` can search for:[As Per MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

1. A word or phrase.
2. The prefix of a word or phrase.
3. A word near another word.

Does that mean that `Contains` can't search for letters?

If yes, then how?

**Edit2:**

```
declare @param as varchar(20)='a'
select * from table1 where Contains(column1,@param)
```

This is Working,

```
declare @param as varchar(20)='"a*"'
select * from table1  where Contains(column1,@param)
```

But,This is Not

```
declare @param as varchar(20)='a'
select * from table1  where Contains(column1,@param+'*')
```

And,

```
select * from table1  where Contains(column1,'"'+@param+'*"')
```

Comment: as per the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx): `Searches for precise or fuzzy (less precise) matches to single words and phrases`. `a` would probably count as noise/[stop-word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx) and be ignored. try `contains(column, 'a*')`

Comment: You need to include double-quotes in your search string.  Look at the examples on the MSDN page that my answer links to.  Those should help you out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use an asterisk to perform a prefix search:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(Column1 , ' "a*" ');
WHERE CONTAINS(Column1 , ' "A*" ');
```

In addition to this, `CONTAINS` is subject to stopword filters. Read up on those [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)

> A stopword can be a word with meaning in a specific language, or it
>   can be a token that does not have linguistic meaning. For example, in
>   the English language, words such as "a," "and," "is," and "the" are
>   left out of the full-text index since they are known to be useless to
>   a search.

To pass input as a parameter, just append the asterisk:

```
declare @SearchThis varchar(10) = 'A'; 
set @SearchThis = quotename(@SearchThis + '*', '"');
select @SearchThis;
```

Once you have the SearchThis setup, you can use in where:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(Column1, @SearchThis)
```

Comment: If Someone Need To Pass The String "A" as a Parameter,Then What Should Be the Syntax?

Comment: `WHERE CONTAINS(Column1, @SearchThis + '*')`, Not Working, Incorrect Syntax Near +

Answer (score 0):

`CONTAINS` is much more powerful than `LIKE`.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)...

> Comparison of LIKE to Full-Text Search
>
> In contrast to full-text search, the LIKE Transact-SQL predicate works
>   on character patterns only. Also, you cannot use the LIKE predicate to
>   query formatted binary data. Furthermore, a LIKE query against a large
>   amount of unstructured text data is much slower than an equivalent
>   full-text query against the same data. A LIKE query against millions
>   of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text
>   query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending
>   on the number of rows that are returned and their size. Another
>   consideration is that LIKE performs only a simple pattern scan of an
>   entire table. A full-text query, in contrast, is language aware,
>   applying specific transformations at index and query time, such as
>   filtering stopwords and making thesaurus and inflectional expansions.
>   These transformations help full-text queries improve their recall and
>   the final ranking of their results.

For your specific concern, you need the prefix search that other answers indicate.  But head to the MSDN page that I linked.  It will help you out.